# Where can I get to download Java comm api?

Tags: java, mobile, sms, usb

I want to write some programs using Java comm api. I am not able to find site/page from which I can download this API. Can anyone please tell me where can I get this API?

Basically I want to send SMS to mobile from PC. Mobile will connect to PC through USB cable. I would also like to know  what are the possible ways to send SMS to mobile? (I am looking for option which wont incur me money)

Thanks in advance !

---

### EDIT 1

I am not allowed to use third party APIs. It seems that Java comm API is dead now. So is there any other way to send messages to mobile from pc?

---

Comment: see my updated answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/8351044/607637

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download javax.comm api library from here : http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcomm20jar.htm

In my opinion, the best alternative to javax.comm is [rxtx](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Download).

---

**Sending SMS over Serial Connection**

For sending sms over serial connection you have to use AT command.

Here are some examples on other languages (but the concept is same).

http://linux-101.org/script/python-code-sending-sms-messages-usb-connected-mobile-phone
http://www.developershome.com/sms/howToSendSMSFromPC.asp
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/AT_commands.aspx

I'd suggest you to test the commands on app like hyperterminal( alternative for win 7 : http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/windows-7-hyperterminal/) first.

Comment: Dead link. Should no longer be the 'Best answer'.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend [RXTX](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Download). It doesn't use the `javax.comm` package, but it follows the same API, with a [little extra](http://users.frii.com/jarvi/rxtx/doc/index.html).

Comment: I am not allowed to use third party APIs. It seems that Java comm API is dead now. So is there any other way to send messages to mobile from pc?

Comment: @Shekhar Why can't you use third party libraries? RXTX 2.0 uses the `javax.comm` package. It's on the same download page above. Other than that, you would have to make your own library to do this.

Comment: well, decision of not using third party api came from management. Cant argue with them...

Answer (score 3):

If this is still relevant for you (maybe others, though);

Serialio.com are the true experts on serial communication. They have an excellent package (SerialPort) which I have used since 1997, and never given me any problems, and since then they have added support for Java Comm API as well as an endless number of platforms.

Answer (score 2):

It might be an older version, but MIT hosts a copy of javaxcomm.zip [here](http://llk.media.mit.edu/projects/picdev/software/javaxcomm.zip).

Answer (score 0):

Try this source at oracle.com:

[Misc. Java SE Tools and Libraries Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-misc-419423.html)

Comment: Oracle only supports a very narrow line of platforms. No Windows, e.g. (What happened to "write once, run everywhere", hm?)