# Java Comm API Package download

Tags: java, linux, api, communication, javax.comm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I get to download Java comm api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350969/where-can-i-get-to-download-java-comm-api)

I'm looking for a link to download sun's javax.comm package for Ubuntu(linux x86 and x64). I looked at this link:
http://java.sun.com/products/javacomm/
But its being re routed to an Oracle web page which gives only the description of the java comm API and no link to download the package. Anyone knows how to go about with this? Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this link :

http://knopflerfish.org/releases/3.1.0/osgi/jars/comm-linux/comm-linux_all-2.0.0.jar

Comment: How is it supposed to work? I have added it to my project as jar file, but I cannot import javax.comm.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-misc-419423.html