# How to download javax.comm on Mac?

Tags: java

In that I connect hardware through USB. I need to write a program in Java to detect the port or pop up GUI page. So I need to communicate with ports. I am looking for javax.comm to download and attach to the eclipse. problem is I have a Mac and not getting link to download java.comm.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle's [page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html) about javax.comm mentions RS-232 and IEEE-1284, but nothing is said about a support for USB. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350969/where-can-i-get-to-download-java-comm-api) says:

> It seems that Java comm API is dead now.

The good news are that there is an API especially for USB: JSR-80. An implementation of it is [usb4java](http://usb4java.org/).